# Which one is correct grammatically, saying "I'm feeling hunger" or "I'm feeling hungry"

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I'm a little bit confused. In "I'm feeling  hunger."  hunger is noun but in "I'm feeling hungry"  hungry is an adjective. which is grammatically correct? what the verb 'feel' follows an adjective or a noun.

Comment: They are both perfectly grammatically correct. However, native speakers only routinely use the ajdective, not the noun, with the verb *feel*.

Comment: The nuance is "I'm feeling hungry" means "I desire food".  "I'm feeling hunger" means "I'm aware of the sensation of hunger".

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct.  "I'm hungry" is the way people say it most often in English.

The verb *to feel* can take either an adjective or a noun, for example:

- I feel uncertain (adj.)
- I feel some uncertainty (noun)

Example of authentic use in conversation:

> "I'm starting to feel hungry.  Shall we take a break and make dinner?"

"I have hunger" is the way this idea is expressed in some other languages, such as Spanish, French and German.  If you want to use *have* for this in English, it would be better to say

> I have a big appetite today.